# Switching Sheets Dynamically - openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, selenium-webdriver, openpyxl

I am new to openpyxl & writing a program that scrapes some data from a site, then writes to an excel workbook.

My program creates (3) standard worksheets & x number of additional sheets based on the # qtags w/in an HTML table. These tags store JS that launches new windows; I need to write the data from these windows to the corresponding worksheet.

To write to each of these new sheets, I need to be able to reference them, but I am having trouble conceiving of a way to save each of them to a variable (ex. sheetx = qtag x's worksheet), considering they are of variable amount. This may be a possible error on my part re: using openpyxl, I am currently writing data through loops like this:

```
lic_table_data = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/div/div[6]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/table/tbody")))

for row_num, row in enumerate(lic_table_data.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"tr"),2):
    cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"td")
    for cell in cells:
        sheet3.cell(row=row_num, column =1+cells.index(cell)).value = cell.text
```

As you can see this relies on me being able to reference the sheetname.cell() & set my values from there.

I feel like I may be over complicating the issue. Is there either:

1. a way to dynamically assign these sheets to variable (I've heard this is frowned upon)
2. a simpler way of writing data to a file (.append has caused me some issues because of the structure of these particular html tables)

I tried to store the index of wb.worksheets[x] w/in values in a list, then just concatenate them w/ the string "Sheet", but still have the problem of actually switching to & populating the sheet.

```
sheets = wb.worksheets[3:]

names=[]
for sheet in sheets:
    names.append("Sheet" + str(sheets.index(sheet)+4))
print(names)
```

Is it possible to then associate each of these names w/ an excel sheet?

Or could I perhaps reference like so:

names[1].cell(row=1, column=1).value